# Simple XML Framework: Strings in elementlist not having namespace prefix when serializing

Tags: java, android, namespaces, prefix, simple-framework

I have this code:

```
@ElementList(name = "Telefono")
@Namespace(reference = "efactura")
protected List<String> telefono;
```

which has an ancester:

```
@Namespace(prefix = "ns2", reference = "efactura")
public class CFEDefType {
```

and it generates:

```
 <ns2:Telefono class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
     <string>12341234</string>
     <string>0303456</string>
 </ns2:Telefono>
```

when I'm expecting:

```
 <ns2:Telefono class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
     <ns2:string>12341234</string>
     <ns2:string>0303456</string>
 </ns2:Telefono>
```

Is is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to do this:

```
@Namespace(prefix = "ns2")
public final class Ns2String extends String {}
```

**UPDATE**
As doppelganger has written in the comments is not possible to extend String (it is final), so he has proposed this (correct) solution:

```
@Root(name="string")
@Namespace(reference = "efactura")
public static class Ns2String {
  @Text
  private String string = null;
  public Ns2String(String string) {
    this.string = string;
  }
  public String getString() {
    return string;
  }
  public void setString(String string) { 
    this.string = string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it kinda worked, first, you can't extend String, but this somehow did it:
@Root(name="string")
    @Namespace(reference = "efactura")
    public static class Ns2String {
        @Text
        private String string = null;

        public Ns2String(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

        public String getString() {
            return string;
        }

        public void setString(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

    }

Comment: Yes, you are right, String is a final class I'll merge your own answer with mine one.